# How can I validate a field client-side using HTML5 that is read only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have an input field that launches a datepicker. To make this work on a mobile device, I've made the field read only. This means that I can launch a date picker on click (or tap) using jQuery, and the tap doesn't open the keyboard on a mobile device.

However - a `readonly` attribute bypasses the HTML5 validation mechanisms. Can I add something that then either mimics the HTML5 validation look and feel, to keep consistency, or that forces HTML5 validation despite the field being `readonly`?

***Edit***: I'm looking for validating that the field is filled in (required) and preferably that it fits a certain date format.

Comment: what kind of validation you want

Comment: a `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` don't prevent the keyboard to show up ?

Comment: @Hacketo: maybe, but they will probably also prevent the datepicker to work. A possible solution can be removing readonly and **blur** the element when focused, but I'm not sure if this will prevent the datepicker to work aswell.

Comment: Doesn't removing the `readonly` attribute while submiting `form` fix it? Can you post concrete sample replicating your issue?

Comment: @briosheje why it would prevent the datepicker to work ?

Comment: @Hacketo: Because it prevents the default action of that input? as far as I can remember preventDefault() or stopPropagation() prevents the datepicker to show up, I'm not 100% sure though, but the solutions provided to similar topics were to use blur and focus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491790/ipad-how-to-prevent-the-keyboard-from-popping-up-on-jquery-datepicker (either using disabled or readonly or onfocus with blur)

Comment: @Hacketo it's a jQuery datepicker where I just do something like `$('.datePicker.).datePicker();` and the plugin sorts it out. Are you saying I should be looking inside the plugin to do a `return false;`? (I think that's how you do those two in jQuery.)

Comment: @A.Wolff that was it! Please post an answer and I'll accept it, or if you're not bothered let me know and I'll post my code and accept it.

Comment: @RobertGrant Ya, you should post it as answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`readonly` fields cannot have the `required` attribute, generally they will already contain some value.

Look at the [HTML5 Standard Drafts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-readonly-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the 'pattern' attribute.

For dates, this pattern might come in handy:

```
^\d{4}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}$|^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$
```

Comment: Thanks - are you saying this will work with a readonly attribute set?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it should be easy to test out, right?

Comment: The premise of my question is that the readonly attribute means validation isn't called. I'm asking if you've got a way round that.