# How to prevent default datepicker of apple product?

Tags: jquery, html

i have one bootstrap date picker.

```
<input name="date2" id="datepicker1" type="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 day')); ?>" />
```

while here is a jquery,

```
$( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
```

because of this in apple products like ipad there are two datepicker shows ,one is of jquery while another is of ipad.

i want to prevent to show the default date picker of apple product with jquery. so how can i do that.

Sorry for weak english/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539292/ipad-web-application-how-do-i-prevent-the-keyboard-from-popping-up-on-jquery-da

Comment: try to change `type="date"` to `type="text"`. had this problem last week in chrome and jQuery Datepicker.

Comment: Thanks man issue solved.