# prevent keyboard from popping up on datepicker mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this page with a booking widget and date picker here:

http://anivillas.com/

(Book your stay)

The following code is set to try and prevent the keyboard from coming up on mobile devices when choosing the datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
 jQuery( ".hasDatepicker" ).hasDatepicker({ 
 }).attr('readonly','readonly');
});
</script>
```

This is working on desktop but not mobile devices.  Does someone know how to  prevent the keyboard from popping up on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (taken from [ipad web application: How do I prevent the keyboard from popping up on jquery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539292/ipad-web-application-how-do-i-prevent-the-keyboard-from-popping-up-on-jquery-da)):

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) 
    { 
        $(this).attr("disabled", false);
    },
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) 
    {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  That code is also currently running now. @user3559787

Answer (score 0):

For others looking for this answer, this is answered here:
[prevent iphone default keyboard when focusing an <input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610758/prevent-iphone-default-keyboard-when-focusing-an-input)

Either of these worked for me - edit the HTML tag as follows, rather than adding JS or jQuery:

```
<input ... readonly="readonly">
<input ... inputmode='none'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the '**readonly**' attribute to the form filed:

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" name="name" required="" readonly>
```