# Get/Set asp:textbox values from javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox

I'm not super familiar with javascript but I'm working on it, I'm trying to do a "same as billing address" type checkbox to fill some textboxes on the same form with data from other textboxes. I found a few solutions online but they weren't working for me. I'm probably overlooking something simple, but I've tried quite a few. Here's what I currently have:

```
function AutoFillBilling()
    {
        var text = document.getElementById("CustContact").Value;
        alert(text); 

    }
```

The alert pops up, but just says undefined, I also tried $("#CustContact").Value to no avail. Below is the textbox I'm trying to access

```
<asp:Textbox runat="server" ID="CustContact" ClientIDMode="Static" type="text" placeholder="Contact" class="required"/>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612413/retrieve-value-from-asptextbox-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties begin with lowercase letters in JavaScript:

```
var text = document.getElementById("CustContact").value;
```

Additionally, while the `ClientIDMode="Static"` certainly *should* be explicitly setting the client-side `id` property, when debugging you may want to examine the HTML just to make sure.  When using JavaScript, looking only at your server-side markup leaves you unnecessarily blind.

Comment: I had confirmed that the IDs were acting as expected. It was the uppercase V causing my issue. Is ClientIDMode acceptable for most browsers or should I do this style: <%# xxxx.ClientID%> in the javascript?

Comment: @JordanWayneCrabb: It shouldn't be browser-dependent.  The biggest consideration to be made is the fact that `id` values need to be unique on the page.  So you might need to make adjustments when using server-side controls inside of things like repeaters or grids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as such

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="Postal_Same_As_PermCheckBox" runat="server" onclick="copyPermAddress(this);" />
```

And JavaScript as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copyPermAddress(e) {
    if (e.checked) {
        document.getElementById('Postal_Adrs_Line_1TextBox').value = document.getElementById('Perm_Adrs_Line_1TextBox').value;
        document.getElementById('Postal_City_VillageTextBox').value = document.getElementById('Perm_City_VillageTextBox').value;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Postal_Adrs_Line_1TextBox").removeAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
        document.getElementById("Postal_City_VillageTextBox").removeAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');
    }
}
```

In this example I am assuming that you are using client id mode as static on the controls mentioned in the JavaScript, if it is not then you may use `<%# xxxx.ClientID%>` blocks to access their IDs