# Displaying the selected text in text area

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
function ShowSelection()
{
    var textComponent = document.getElementById('TextArea1');
    var selectedText;
    if (document.selection != undefined) {
        textComponent.focus();
        var sel = document.selection.createRange();
        selectedText = sel.text;
    }
    else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined) {
        var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
        var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
        selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos,endPos)
    }
    alert("You selected: " + selectedText)
}
</script>

<asp:TextBox id="TextArea1" TextMode="MultiLine" runat="server">/asp:TextBox>
<a href="#" onclick=alert(ShowSelection());>Click here to display the selected text</a>
```

Here I am trying to display the selected text by user. I need to display the text which is selected by user.But unfortunately event is not triggering.. Any wrong in this code. Please give me solution..

Comment: you need to access the asp servercontrols in Js using the following way  `var textComponent = document.getElementById('<%=TextArea1.ClientID %>');`

Comment: the above javascript code seems to work fine with the basic html, you are selecting the text in the wrong way , have a look here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612413/retrieve-value-from-asptextbox-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your same code worked for me in fiddle, just not asp.net :

```
    <script>
  function ShowSelection() {
    var textComponent = document.getElementById('TextArea1');
    var selectedText;
    if (document.selection != undefined) {
      textComponent.focus();
      var sel = document.selection.createRange();
      selectedText = sel.text;
    } else if (textComponent.selectionStart != undefined) {
      var startPos = textComponent.selectionStart;
      var endPos = textComponent.selectionEnd;
      selectedText = textComponent.value.substring(startPos, endPos)
    }
    alert("You selected: " + selectedText)
  }

</script>

<input id="TextArea1" type="textarea" />
<a href="ShowSelection()" onclick="ShowSelection()">click me </a>
```

Point is Why are you calling alert on `ShowSelection()` function again, that function itself is alerting, not returning any string value.

Please check.

Answer (score 0):

Few Suggestions:

Here in your code `TextArea1` is an ASP control, You will not get or set it's value like as you did in the given code. To make it working you can do any of the following:

1. Change the Asp textBox to an HTML TextBot: so the tag will be like the following:

   ```
    <input type="text" id="TextArea1"/>
   ```

include `runat="server"`  if you want to access it in back-end

2. Change the script to get the value properly as like Webruster suggested in the comment. or From [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039544/getting-textbox-value-in-javascript)

   ```
   var textComponent = document.getElementById('<%=TextArea1.ClientID %>');
   ```

   One more thing i have to say is that, the anchor tag. no need to show an extra alert because of two reasons:

   - The method is not returning anything
   - Content is already alerted inside the called method

So the `<a>` will be like the following:

```
<a href="#" onclick=ShowSelection();>Click here to display the selected text</a>
```

Comment: Hey Sorry. Previously it didn't came. But now its coming fine. but not able to display the selected data.